# How to cancel selection in ListView?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I try to cancel user selection in a ListView according a condition. I tried to consume mouse clicked and mouse pressed event in ListView and ListCell but it didn't work. I don't understand why bu events occur after the selected item property change. 
How can I cancel the user selection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to prevent users from selecting items by clicking on it. I further suppose that you tried a solution like this:

```
listView.addEventHandler(MOUSE_CLICKED, click -> click.consume());
```

That does not prevent other click handlers from being executed. Even if it did, the internal event handler seems to be fired before your event handler, since the selected item is changed before your handler is executed.

You need to add an *event filter* to prevent any event handlers from being fired:

```
listView.addEventFilter(MOUSE_CLICKED, click -> click.consume());
```

Comment: This isn't working. The selectedItemProperty has been set before this event occurs.

Comment: This works, but this event is also being fired then the scrollbar is being clicked on. Do you know a workaround that?

Answer (score 3):

```
    listView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
```

Comment: Its often better to have a brief explanation than to have code only answers.

Comment: Solved my problem, this is exactly what I was looking for. +1