# Disable item selection in ListView

Tags: listview, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to disable item selection in a `ListView` but to no avail. I tried this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26872071/8528561) but it isn't working. I also naively tried setting the selection model to null but that also didn't work

I need to disable the selection since in each cell there are buttons and the selection is not necessary at all and it is also interfering with the inner controls.

Comment: does this work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621752/javafx-make-listview-not-selectable-via-mouse ?

Comment: @k88 No since I still need to interact with some buttons inside each cell.  I will update my question

Comment: If you really just need to change the appearance, you can do that with CSS (basically just revert the styles for a selected cell back to the default). If you actually want to turn off selection entirely, you'll need to implement a selection model from scratch that always has nothing selected.

Comment: @James_D Just to be sure, is my assumption that the selection model is interfering with the click events of the buttons in each cell? I'm asking since I guess that implementing a selection model from scratch can be very tedious and may not be necessary

Comment: No clue - I wouldn’t expect that to happen though. I would create and post a [MCVE].

Comment: @James_D Alright, I'll try to come up with an example for that. Thank you